# How do I prove this statement is a tautology without using truth tables (transformation proof)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I think I'm just being dumb. I've manged to work it out via a truth table as I thought that would help with working it out using a transformation proof, but I'm really struggling. Any guidance is appreciated.

Here is my statement: **

> (p ∧ ¬ q) ⇒ ¬ (¬ p ∧ q)

** Thank you in advance.

Comment: The consequent is equivalent to $p\lor\lnot q$ by de Morgan's law and double-negation elimination. The result is then obvious. $p\land\lnot q$ implies $p$, which in turn implies $p\lor\lnot q$.

Comment: Are you familiar with natural deduction?  The proposition is fairly straightforward to prove using it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:
\begin{align}
(p\land\neg q)\to\neg(\neg p\land q)&\equiv\neg(p\land\neg q)\lor\neg(\neg q\land q)\tag{material implication}\\[1em]
&\equiv (\neg p\lor q)\lor(p\lor\neg q)\tag{De Morgan}\\[1em]
&\equiv (\neg p\lor p)\lor (q\lor\neg q)\tag{associativity}\\[1em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}\lor\mathbf{T}\tag{negation}\\[1em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}.\tag{domination}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that [(p ∧ ¬ q) ⇒ ¬ (¬ p ∧ q)] is false.  Then (p ∧ ¬ q) is true.  ¬ (¬ p ∧ q) is false.
Thus, (¬ p ∧ q) is true.  So, ¬ p is true.  p also holds true.  We have a contradiction.

Therefore, [(p ∧ ¬ q) ⇒ ¬ (¬ p ∧ q)] is true.

Comment: Thank you, helped me understand a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two proofs in a [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/).

1. This is an indirect proof similar to what Doug Spoonwood suggested:

[image]

2. This is a direct proof:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/